# Jquery not functioning- radiobutton

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i am trying to create a webapp that find the area for the selected shape according to the parameters for it is provided.

so i am halfway stuck.

when the radio button is clicked, the parameter textboxes should load in the values div. i tried using jquery for this to function,  but when the radio button is checked the textboxes are not loaded into the div.

please help. i cant find where i am going wrong.

***JQuery***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="circle")
        {
           $('.values').innerHTML="<table class='table table-default'><tbody><tr><td>
           <label for='circlerad'>Radius:</label></td><td><input type='text'
            class='form-control' name='circlerad' maxlength='10'></td></tr></tbody>
            </table>";
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="square")
        {
            $('.values').innerHTML="<table class='table table-default'><tbody><tr><td>
           <label for='sqside'>Side-length</label></td><td><input type='text'
            class='form-control' name='sqside' maxlength='10'></td></tr></tbody>
            </table>";
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="rectangle")
        {
            $('.values').innerHTML="<table class='table table-default'><tbody><tr><td>
           <label for='reclen'>Length:</label></td><td><input type='text'
            class='form-control' name='reclen' maxlength='10'></td></tr>
            <tr><td>
           <label for='recbr'>Breadth:</label></td><td><input type='text'
            class='form-control' name='recbr' maxlength='10'></td></tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>";
        }
    });
});
```

***html/php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Area Finder</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

  <?php

    echo("<center><h1>Area Finder!</h1></center><div class='conatiner'><div class='row'><form role='form' action='./arearesult.php' method='POST'><div class='form-group'><div class='panel panel-primary col-xs-3'><div class='panel-heading'>Select a shape</div><div class=' panel-body'>");
    echo("<table class='table table-default'><tbody>");
    echo("<tr><td>Circle</td><td><input type='radio' name=shape value='circle'></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Square</td><td><input type='radio' name=shape value='square'></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Rectangle</td><td><input type='radio' name=shape value='rectangle'></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div>");
    echo("<div class='col-xs-1'></div><div class='panel panel-primary col-xs-5'><div class='panel-heading'>Enter values</div>");
    echo("<div class='values panel-body'><table class='table table-default'><tbody>");

    echo("</form></div></div>");
  ?>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src='js/parameters.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[area finder webpage](http://www.avudo.tk/areafinder.php)

Comment: did you check value of the radio button is taken correct

Comment: well i hav posted the whole code.. u can check... i have given the values correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is on `$('.values').innerHTML` assignment.

It should be like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "circle") {
      $('.values').html("<table class='table table-default'><tbody><tr><td>" +
    "<label for='circlerad'>Radius:</label></td><td><input type='text' " +
    "class='form-control' name='circlerad' maxlength='10'></td></tr></tbody>" +
    "</table>");
    }
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "square") {
      $('.values').html("<table class='table table-default'><tbody><tr><td>" +
    "<label for='sqside'>Side-length</label></td><td><input type='text'" +
    "class='form-control' name='sqside' maxlength='10'></td></tr></tbody>" +
    "</table>");
    }
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "rectangle") {
      $('.values').html("<table class='table table-default'><tbody><tr><td>" +
    "<label for='reclen'>Length:</label></td><td><input type='text'" +
    "class='form-control' name='reclen' maxlength='10'></td></tr>" +
    "<tr><td>" +
    "<label for='recbr'>Breadth:</label></td><td><input type='text'" +
    "class='form-control' name='recbr' maxlength='10'></td></tr>" +
    "</tbody>" +
    "</table>");
    }
  });
});
```

UPDATE: Changed to `$('.values').html()` see working plunker https://jsfiddle.net/u0hd5Lmq/

Read https://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings

Comment: what difference does this make, i tried it. it still doesnt work.

Comment: You need to concatenate your multiline string.

Comment: yaa i did that.. but its still the same.

Comment: Updated the code in my answer, you need to make sure all multiline string in your script are concatenated. It will produce an error which caused your script to break. check your console for error and you'll see

Comment: i have tried it bro... not working.... u can take my above code and try it urself in your browser.. let me know if it works for u..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100217/discussion-between-princeg-and-vishnuprasad-venugopal).

Answer (score 0):

you change your code to this format it will work

```
$('.values').html("<table class='table table-default'><tbody><tr><td>
           <label for='circlerad'>Radius:</label></td><td><input type='text'
            class='form-control' name='circlerad' maxlength='10'></td></tr></tbody>
            </table>");
```